# Webpack issues after building Angular library

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, webpack

I'm trying to turn an existing Angular component into a library. It was a component that was ripped from an existing project, so I created a new local Angular project to contain just the component of interest, brang over the code I needed, ran `npm start`, and can observe that the component works. It uses plotly.js and Angular Material, etc, appears to function as desired.

I then created a new Angular project and followed these steps: https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries to create a library.

so, I did the following: ng new spectrogram --no-create-application -> copied the working components/module from the new previous project I was talking about into the library src/lib/ -> ng build spectrogram -> cd dist/spectrogram -> npm publish

Then pulled the npm package I just published into a new project.

It looks like I'm getting a bunch of webpack related errors though (I think?)

when I run `npm start` on the project that imports the library, I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at 73592 (index.js:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 63595 (plot_api.js:5:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 9288 (index.js:3:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 13768 (core.js:16:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 35346 (core.js:3:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
```

I tried a hacky fix I found elsewhere on stackoverflow, which was to add:

```
  <script>
    if (global === undefined) {
      var global = window;
    }
  </script>
```

to index.html, but then I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at 92904 (util.js:109:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 17066 (assertion_error.js:35:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 55886 (assert.js:36:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 24386 (index.js:6:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 49934 (common.js:5:20)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
```

So it seems like there's just an issue with webpack all around.

In my actual Library application (that I publish as an npm package), this is the output from npm list webpack:

```
➜  generic-spectrogram git:(master) ✗ npm list webpack
generic-spectrogram@0.0.1 /home/dev/AIR6500/generic-spectrogram
├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.1
│ ├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.1602.1
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ @ngtools/webpack@16.2.1
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ babel-loader@9.1.3
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ copy-webpack-plugin@11.0.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ css-loader@6.8.1
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ less-loader@11.1.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ mini-css-extract-plugin@2.7.6
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ postcss-loader@7.3.3
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ sass-loader@13.3.2
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ source-map-loader@4.0.1
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ webpack-dev-middleware@6.1.1
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ webpack-dev-server@4.15.1
│ │ ├─┬ webpack-dev-middleware@5.3.3
│ │ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ webpack-subresource-integrity@5.1.0
│ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
│ └─┬ webpack@5.88.2
│   └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.9
│     └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
└─┬ @nx/angular@16.7.4
  ├─┬ @nx/webpack@16.7.4
  │ ├─┬ copy-webpack-plugin@10.2.4
  │ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  │ ├─┬ css-minimizer-webpack-plugin@5.0.1
  │ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  │ ├─┬ fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@7.2.13
  │ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  │ ├─┬ mini-css-extract-plugin@2.4.7
  │ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  │ ├─┬ postcss-loader@6.2.1
  │ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  │ ├─┬ sass-loader@12.6.0
  │ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  │ ├─┬ source-map-loader@3.0.2
  │ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  │ ├─┬ style-loader@3.3.3
  │ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  │ ├─┬ stylus-loader@7.1.3
  │ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  │ ├─┬ ts-loader@9.4.4
  │ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
```

In the project I import that library into, here is the output:

```
➜  spectrogram-test-2 git:(feature/CRD-979_spectrogram) ✗ npm list webpack
spectrogram-test-2@0.0.0 /home/dev/AIR6500/spectrogram-test-2
└─┬ @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.1
  ├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.1602.1
  │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  ├─┬ @ngtools/webpack@16.2.1
  │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  ├─┬ babel-loader@9.1.3
  │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  ├─┬ copy-webpack-plugin@11.0.0
  │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  ├─┬ css-loader@6.8.1
  │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  ├─┬ less-loader@11.1.0
  │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  ├─┬ mini-css-extract-plugin@2.7.6
  │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  ├─┬ postcss-loader@7.3.3
  │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  ├─┬ sass-loader@13.3.2
  │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  ├─┬ source-map-loader@4.0.1
  │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  ├─┬ webpack-dev-middleware@6.1.1
  │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  ├─┬ webpack-dev-server@4.15.1
  │ ├─┬ webpack-dev-middleware@5.3.3
  │ │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  ├─┬ webpack-subresource-integrity@5.1.0
  │ └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
  └─┬ webpack@5.88.2
    └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.9
      └── webpack@5.88.2 deduped
```

Have I missed some steps along the way or something? First time trying to turn something into an Angular library, so I probably have.

Here is my angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "spectrogram-test-2": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/spectrogram-test-2",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "spectrogram-test-2:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "spectrogram-test-2:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "spectrogram-test-2:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```